# Replace a variable number of asterisks with NaN in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to scrub some climate data from the US NCDC and it has columns with a varying number of asterisks to indicate empty fields.  I want to replace those with `np.nan`.

I have tried to do it with `df.replace` but am struggling with the regex syntax to handle the variable length of asterisks in a field.
I suspect that I need something like `df.replace('?', np.NaN)` but where the `'?'` is a regex to match any number of asterisks.

Here is a clip of the data:

```
USAF    WBAN    YR--MODAHRMN    DIR     SPD     GUS     CLG     SKC     L   M   ...     SLP     ALT     STP     MAX     MIN     PCP01   PCP06   PCP24   PCPXX   SD
0   722543  12977   200601010053    160     6   ***     722     CLR     *   *   ...     1010.9  29.83   1007.2  ***     ***     0.00    *****   *****   *****   **
1   722543  12977   200601010153    160     9   ***     722     CLR     *   *   ...     1011.0  29.83   1007.2  ***     ***     0.00    *****   *****   *****   **
2   722543  12977   200601010253    160     9   ***     722     CLR     *   *   ...     1011.1  29.83   1007.2  ***     ***     0.00    *****   *****   *****   **
3   722543  12977   200601010313    160     10  ***     722     SCT     *   *   ...     ******  29.83   1007.2  ***     ***     *****   *****   *****   *****   **
4   722543  12977   200601010321    160     10  ***     4       BKN     *   *   ...     ******  29.83   1007.2  ***     ***     *****   *****   *****   *****   **
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.replace` with regex pattern `'^\*+$'` works well enough for this:

```
In [790]: df.replace('^\*+$', np.nan, regex=True)
Out[790]: 
     USAF   WBAN  YR--MODAHRMN  DIR  SPD  GUS  CLG  SKC   L   M     SLP  \
0  722543  12977  200601010053  160    6  NaN  722  CLR NaN NaN  1010.9   
1  722543  12977  200601010153  160    9  NaN  722  CLR NaN NaN  1011.0   
2  722543  12977  200601010253  160    9  NaN  722  CLR NaN NaN  1011.1   
3  722543  12977  200601010313  160   10  NaN  722  SCT NaN NaN     NaN   

     ALT     STP  MAX  MIN PCP01  PCP06  PCP24  PCPXX  SD  
0  29.83  1007.2  NaN  NaN  0.00    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN  
1  29.83  1007.2  NaN  NaN  0.00    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN  
2  29.83  1007.2  NaN  NaN  0.00    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN  
3  29.83  1007.2  NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
```